# solve 401 Jira with Python

Tags: python

**Use case**: Login to Jira server from python.

**Error**: 401

**Solutio**n: added (based on a suggestion from this site) into my py code

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
logging.captureWarnings(True)
```

If you need my version of Jira login from python, please let me know.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question